# Cant Connect to Local SQL Server 2000 instance in code (but no problem with SQL Management studio)

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, sql-server

I have just moved from Vista to Windows 7 with my development environment and ALL OF A SUDDEN my web app cannot connect to the local SQL Server instance

**[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.**

Funily enough, SQL Management studio express can connect fine. The connection string im using is:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Data Source=.\myinstance;Password=xxx
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses, I fixed the problem by changing the connection string as follows:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Network Library=DBNMPNTW;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Data Source=\\.\pipe\MSSQL$myinstance\sql\query;Password=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the ALIAS on Microsoft Client Network Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the "Login" that you are using, through SSMS. Also read the error for any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you installed the database instance in Windows Only authentication mode and sa is disabled.